# Is there any alternative javascript function available for draggable containment in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I need alternative js code for draggable containment like in jquery. I've referred this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable and some other online references. Need alternative

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: @PHPglue am not asking for drag and drop. am looking for draggable with  containment

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use pure jaascript. please refer my [jsfiddle][1] link.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/avog0xwk/
```

Comment: Yes i can. But the problem is i need alternative solution in javascript

Comment: it is good @Negi Rox but http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/zN62s/ pls see how this containment  working. this is what i need exactly in JS

Comment: but you are looking for javascript solution

Comment: Yes @Negi . But for draggable, I already have a solution. I mentioned in the question. I need for containment

Comment: ok updating my fiddle wait

Comment: @Stephen please take a look in updated fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184248/discussion-between-stephen-and-negi-rox).

Answer (score 0):

I think bellow code is helpful for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, 
        initial-scale=1.0, 
        user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Drag/Drop/Bounce</title>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: #333;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 7px;
      touch-action: none;
    }
    #item {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);


      touch-action: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    #item:active {
      background-color: rgba(168, 218, 220, 1.00);
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="item">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var dragItem = document.querySelector("#item");
    var container = document.querySelector("#container");

    var active = false;
    var currentX;
    var currentY;
    var initialX;
    var initialY;
    var xOffset = 0;
    var yOffset = 0;

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

    container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

    function dragStart(e) {
      if (e.type === "touchstart") {
        initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset;
        initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset;
      } else {
        initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
        initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
      }

      if (e.target === dragItem) {
        active = true;
      }
    }

    function dragEnd(e) {
      initialX = currentX;
      initialY = currentY;

      active = false;
    }

    function drag(e) {
      if (active) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.type === "touchmove") {
          currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
          currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
        } else {
          currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
          currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
        }

        xOffset = currentX;
        yOffset = currentY;

        setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
      }
    }

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI Dragable. https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

```html
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <style>
          #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
          </style>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
          $( function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment", scroll: false });
          } );
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="containment"> 
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
          <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
        </div>
         
         
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: i'm in the need of Containment window @Mr.Turtle

Comment: @Stephen I edited my answer. You can now only drag the #draggable inside the containment div.

Comment: Yeah @Mr.Tutrle i got. But i need the same in Javascript. i already tried in jquery